# How to Run a Command in the Computer Terminal Through Python

Tags: python, linux, terminal, text-to-speech

I am trying to make a TTS (Text to Speech) program and I have found an easy way to do that is to run the "say ''" command in the terminal. However, when I looked to see how to run the terminal command through python I found this:`import os
os.system("echo 'hello world'")` it doesn't seem to work with my laptop (I'm running Linux). Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: i’m guessing it has to do with your usage of `’`

Answer (score 2):

It works without problem:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('echo "hello world"')
hello world
0
```

From python 2.7 to 3.6 at least, your problem are the quotes marks.

Comment: @usr2564301: Why would the single quotes break the shell?  They’re supported there too.

Comment: When I did that, I got the same result as when i used the code I had found: nothing.